# How to remove trailing slash from Magento 2 url

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, redirect, htaccess

I have installed ssl in my Magento 2 store and configured base url to the https version.

But when accessing http version, Magento redirecting url with appending trailing slash.

**For example:**

My domain is `example.com`

**Base url** saved in configuration is `https://www.example.com`

When I accessing http version `http://www.example.com/contactus.html`

it is redirecting to `https://www.example.com/contactus.html/`

Could you please help to remove the trailing slash while redirecting.

Comment: Hi I have to remove trailing slash for cms page can U advise me how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

***Magento admin you can use store direct_url for remove trailing slash.***

***example:***

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='contact-us'}}">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Hi @savan patel i have tried this but no luck. Can you advise me alternative way

Comment: Hello @NagarajuK Please try to do re-indexing and clean & flush Magento Cache and Browser Cache and check again

Answer (score 1):

ADD this code  so trailing slash remove

$hreflangUrl= https://www.example.com/contactus.html/
$result = rtrim($hreflangUrl, "/"); 
$result=https://www.example.com/contactus.html

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in  the end of your root's **.htaccess file** -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] #
```

Comment: I have tried the redirect code as per your suggestion. But it leads to infinite redirect loop. Any other solution?

Comment: This will cause redirect loop on admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept base magento 2 methods to rtrim the trailing slash. But it could lead to errors. Here is the example: https://github.com/vsevolod-tarasov/links